# Update OS Via Ansible Determine What Distrubution Major Version

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, ansible

I've created an Ansible role that consists of no more than tasks and some variables. Probably overkill at this point but I plan to expand on the role sometime in the future.  I'm attempting to first determine what OS is running (RHEL 7 or 8 in my case) and then update with either yum or dnf.

Here is the playbook I'm using to include the role:

**`$ more playbooks/UpdateAllPackages.yml`**

```yaml
---
- name: Update All Packages
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - { role: roles/UpdateAllPackages }
```

The role:

**`$ more role/UpdateAllPackages/tasks/main.yml`**

```yaml
---
- name: Update All RHEL 7 Packages Via YUM
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: "{{ PkgInclude }}"
    state: "{{ PkgVers  }}"
    enablerepo: "{{ RepoEnable }}"
    disablerepo: "{{ RepoDisable }}"
  when: ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_major_version']=="7"
  register: YumStandardOutput

- name: Print Errors If The Yum Update Encounters Any Errors
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "Yum Update Encounted Errors Please Investigate"
  when: YumStandardOutput is not defined

- name: Update All RHEL 8 Packages Via DNF
  ansible.builtin.dnf:
    name: "{{ PkgInclude }}"
    state: "{{ PkgVers  }}"
    enablerepo: "{{ RepoEnable }}"
    disablerepo: "{{ RepoDisable }}"
  when: ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_major_version']=="8"
  register: DnfStandardOutput

- name: Print Errors If The Yum Update Encounters Any Errors
  debug:
    msg: "Dnf Update Encounted Errors Please Investigate"
  when: DnfStandardOutput is not defined
```

And the associated variables:

**`$ more roles/UpdateAllPackages/defaults/main.yml`**

```yaml
---
PkgInclude: "*"
PkgExclude: ""
PkgVers: "latest"
RepoEnable: "rhel-?-for-x86_64-appstream-e4s-rpms,rhel-?-for-x86_64-appstream-eus-rpms,rhel-?-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms,rhel-?-for-x86_64-baseos-e4s-rpms,rhel-?
-for-x86_64-baseos-eus-rpms,rhel-?-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms,ansible-2-for-rhel-?-x86_64-rpms"
RepoDisable: "rhel-?-for-x86_64-sap-netweaver-e4s-rpms,rhel-?-for-x86_64-sap-netweaver-eus-rpms,rhel-?-for-x86_64-sap-netweaver-rpms,rhel-?-for-x86_64-sap-solut
ions-e4s-rpms,rhel-?-for-x86_64-sap-solutions-eus-rpms,rhel-?-for-x86_64-sap-solutions-rpms"
```

When I run the playbook with

```shell
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/<name of inventory>.ini --limit=<name of server> playbooks/UpdateAllPackages.yml --extra-vars=@./vault/<name of vault>.yml
```

it fails with the following error:

```json
PLAY [Update All Packages] *************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [UpdateAllPackages : Update All RHEL 7 Packages Via YUM] **************************************************************************************************
fatal: [<name of server>]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_major_version']==\"7\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_major_version']==\"7\"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_distribution_major_version'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ansible/roles/UpdateAllPackages/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: Update All RHEL 7 Packages Via YUM\n  ^ here\n"}
```

What is that telling me?  From what I can gather, it's saying that the dictionary object
`ansible_distribution_major_version` is empty (has no attribute).

Thinking that may be the case, I ran the following on the source server:

```
$ ansible localhost -m ansible.builtin.setup -a 'filter=ansible_distribution_major_version'
```

Which yielded:

```json
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "7"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Then I thought perhaps there was a gotcha associated with `gather_facts` being set to `no` within the playbook so I changed it to `yes`.  Still, the same problem/error persists.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According the error message

```yaml
'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_distribution_major_version'
```

it seems that facts were not gathered. For debugging purpose and to narrow down the cause in your environment, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - distribution
    - '!all'
    - '!min'

  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: ansible_facts

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  ansible_facts:
    distribution: RedHat
    distribution_file_parsed: true
    distribution_file_path: /etc/redhat-release
    distribution_file_search_string: Red Hat
    distribution_file_variety: RedHat
    distribution_major_version: '7'
    distribution_release: Maipo
    distribution_version: '7.9'
    gather_subset:
    - distribution
    - '!all'
    - '!min'
    module_setup: true
    os_family: RedHat

TASK [debug] **********************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '7'
```

**Further Reading**

- [Getting full name of the OS using Ansible facts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71035723/6771046)
- [What is the exact list of Ansible `setup` `min`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046)
- [How Ansible sets variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71043335/6771046)